# Pinned sections on top of the view in LazyHGrid

Tags: swiftui, lazyhgrid

I have searched a lot of this issue, How to achieve pinning the section on top of the view while we have horizontal scrolling in `LazyHGrid` similar to **Native Emoji keyboard**, we might have a workaround?

**Updated**

```
ScrollView(.horizontal) {
    LazyHGrid(rows: rows, spacing: 6, pinnedViews: [.sectionHeaders]) {
                
        ForEach(EmojiCategory.all, id: \.id) { category in
            Section(header:
                VStack {
                    Text(category.title)
                        .font(.caption)
                        .bold()
                        .textCase(.uppercase)
                        .opacity(0.4)
                    }
                    .frame(maxHeight: .infinity)
                    .background(.clear)
                                  
            ) {
                ForEach(category.emojis, id: \.id) { emoji in
                    Text(emoji.char)
                        .font(.title)
                    }
                }
              }
                
            }.frame(height: 180)
        }
    }
}
```

**Result**

[image]

**Expected Result**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Its working fine you are just missing the background, so it won't looks like the items are passing through

```
Section(header:
    VStack {
        Text("Test")
        .font(.caption)
        .bold()
        .textCase(.uppercase)
        .opacity(0.4)
    }
    .frame(maxHeight: .infinity)
    .background(.white)
)
{}
```

Comment: Same results, I meant, the title need to be above emojis similar to `CollectionView` behavior in UIKit

Comment: Would you mind update the code so I can  replicate the whole issue?

Comment: Updated, please check.

Comment: I was talking about `EmojiCategory.all` and `rows`

Comment: Ah sorry, `EmojiCategory.all` is array of Strings, and rows is array of GridItem `var rows: [GridItem] =
            Array(repeating: .init(.adaptive(minimum: 30, maximum: 30)), count: 5)`

Comment: Check my answer again, but instead of `.white` put `.black`

Comment: I am afraid there is a misunderstanding, white or black the pinned view will be on the left which I'm trying to achieve the expected result. Check the update question I attached the expected result to be more clear.